# Which mat-menu was selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The Angular Material documentation shows us the markup for `mat-menu`:

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

But does not show how to capture which `mat-menu-item` was selected.  How do we do this?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just needed to identify which menu item was selected in the even handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not found it in Angular documentation, but as you have used button in mat-menu-item, you can use its `click` event to capture the selected value like below

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="selectedMenu('Redial')">
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
```